# Show created date for articles in a certain category (Joomla 2.5)

Tags: joomla2.5

My article settings are set to hide the date by default. But for the "News" category, I would like to show the created (or published date) in the article view. How do I only show the date in this category?

I've tried playing around with the menu item parameters (its a category blog item linking to the news category), but that only controls date visibility in the category view. Not the article view.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting it for each article individually?